# Using WHERE CLAUSE with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, having, where-in

I want to display the total value of items sold for each bill using 2 tables -

Here is the table items, Structure of table is I_Code->int, Name->Varchar, Category->Varchar, Rate->int
[image]

And this is table bills, Structure of table is BillNo->int, Date->date, 
I_Code->int, qty->int

[image]

Here is the query I am trying to get desired output

```
SELECT i.`rate` * b.`qty`, b.`BillNo` FROM bills b, items i WHERE b.I_Code=i.I_Code GROUP BY `BillNo` ;
```

But output is not correct
[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT SUM(A.TOT), b.`BillNo`
FROM (
    SELECT i.`rate` * b.`qty` AS TOT, b.`BillNo`
    FROM bills b, items i
    WHERE b.I_Code = i.I_Code
) AS A
GROUP BY `BillNo`;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(i.`rate` * b.`qty`) AS TOT, b.`BillNo`
FROM bills b, items i
WHERE b.I_Code = i.I_Code
GROUP BY `BillNo`;
```

Comment: I was very near to the lane, thanx to you for showing me the narrow lane.